# updateRequestProcessorChain not working for Solr Document

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

In my solr core I don't see the aList_s created in my document .I have not specified this in db-data-config.xml and bList is not converting to a single value.I have specified this in db-data-config.xm. , I still bList  has multiplevalue. Using Solr5. Am I missing anything?

```
My solrConfig.xml below
      
      <updateRequestProcessorChain name="my-conversion">
        <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="source">aList</str>
        <str name="dest">aList_s</str>
        </processor>
        <processor class="solr.FirstFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldName">bList</str>
        </processor>
      </updateRequestProcessorChain>
    
    My schema for this looks like
    
    <field name="aList"  type="string_ci"    indexed="false" required="false" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />  
    <field name="aList_s"  type="string_ci"    indexed="false" required="false" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />    
    <field name="bList"  type="string_ci"    indexed="false" required="false" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```

Comment: Are you specifying the update processor to be run anywhere? It won't be run without being specified - i.e without `my-conversion` being referenced somewhere. Usually you give this as `update.chain=my-conversion` when sending an update to Solr, but I'm not sure if the data import handler (if that's what you're using) supports URPCs.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have not specifying it any where..sorry not sure I understand  where do I provide my-conversion update.chain=my-conversion.. I can change the name   my-conversion to what ever default dataImporthandler uses..the name is need not be specific

Comment: I see this is already configured  in solrConfig.xml  <initParams path="/update/**">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">my-conversion</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>